# Retrieving data from database in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to display data from my database

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Text="TopAggregate:" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF0F274E" Height="25" Width="80" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyDictionaryConverter}, ConverterParameter=, Mode=OneWay}"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF0F274E" Height="25" Width="240" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

these are the only lead I have for achieving this, I just need to know what the converter parameter should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter parameter should be the column name in your table of data that you want to retrieve

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with your column name of your table. There you go